# Why does recursive function count downwards after peak?

Tags: c, recursion

with fear that I may overstep another question of mine (although this is a new problem alltogether) I still ask this question.

I have this code:

```
int blob_count(int y, int x, int gridCopy[][5], int sum){

    //Local vars
    int posX, posY;

    //Find the position 1 behind and 1 above the starting point, and start the loop there
    for(posX = -1;posX <=1; posX++){
        for(posY = -1; posY <= 1; posY++){
            if((y + posY) >= 0 && (x + posX) >= 0){
                if((y + posY) <= 5 && (x + posX) <= 5){
                    if(gridCopy[posY+y][posX+x] == 1){
                        //Set the starting point to 0 (so it wont get calculated again)
                        gridCopy[posY+y][posX+x] = 0;



                        y = posY+y;
                        x = posX+x;

                        sum++;
                        blob_count(y, x, gridCopy, sum);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The issue is that sum, which counts up 1, for each recursive run, returns the wrong value. By doing a print for each recursive run it gives the result:

```
sum = 1  
sum = 2  
sum = ...  
sum = n
```

Which is great, however, by setting printing out the sum outside the for loop (right before return sum;) the opposite happens when it has peaked, so it does this:

```
sum = n  
sum = ...  
sum = 2  
sum = 1  

return sum; // = 1
```

Which is obviously wrong, as I want the total count, not the lowest. Have I got the return value the wrong place? I've tried putting it in right after the recursive call (inside the loop), to no avail.

Comment: `blob_count` operates on a new `sum` every time it is called. You may want to pass a pointer to sum rather than its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay let's get rid of the extra bits and simplify your problem down to the essentials.
You have:

```
int blob_count(int sum)
{
    sum++;

    if (sum < 10)
        blob_count(sum);

    return sum;
}
```

If you add `printf("sum==%d\n", sum)` right before the `return` then it will be called first at the innermost recursion (where sum == 10), then it will `return` to the next level out where `sum == 9`, print that, return to `sum == 8` and so on.

If you put it before the recursive call to `blob_count(sum)` then you'll print the values before you recurse down, so they start with `sum==0, sum == 1` and so on.

---

If you want `sum`to be the deepest level your recursion got to, then you could either pass it back via the return value like this:

```
int blob_count(int sum)
{
    sum++;

    if (sum < 10)
        sum = blob_count(sum);

    return sum;
}
```

or you could pass it via a pointer so that the original variable gets modified:

```
void blob_count(int* sum)
{
    *sum++;

    if (*sum < 10)
        blob_count(sum);

    return;
}
```

The first one is probably the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Epic bud! It turns out my problem specifically was that i did not set sum = blob_count(sum), which in return caused my return value to misfit. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think more generally your problem is that you're trying to use recursion when you don't really understand it. But glad to be of help. :)

Comment: that's probably true, but I guess I need to study Software Engineering for 5 years for a reason, and seeing I've been around for 2 months on my university, I don't really expect to know everything yet, especially not about recursion seeing I've had one 2 hour lecture about it so far.

Answer (score 1):

What pmg said. For each recursive call, the current value of sum is copied and the copy is passed to the recursive call. If you want to modify objects in functions, you must pass a pointer to these objects instead of the object itself.

Comment: Pointers are still rather new to me, any chance you could give a quick example? Can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @Kola GrahamS has an example of how in his answer. As he said, it's probably easier here to just assign the return value of blob_count to sum. If you need to modify more than one argument, however, you need to pass pointers, study his example carefully to learn how to do that.